# Select records that does not exist in another table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables - `"Customer"` table and `"Blacklist"` customer table. When I blacklist a customer, I put the `CusId` as a foreign key into to Blacklist table.

What I want to do is get CusId and Name that are not in the BlackList Table.

How can I achieve this in Entity Framework C#?

```
Customer
---------
(CusId,Name,Telephone,Email)

Blacklist
---------
(CusId)
```

Comment: I am new to EF and I hv already tried variours ways. None of them did work. So please help me to fix this matter.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

What you want is something like the following:

```
db.Customers
    .Where(c => !db.Blacklists
        .Select(b => b.CusId)
        .Contains(c.CusId)
    );
```

EF will happily turn that into a sub-query that will run quite well.

This pattern works for static lists (creates an `IN(a, b, c)` expression) as well as other tables. You can use it to check for being in the list or not in the list.

If you want to test it and see the SQL it generates, I strongly recommend LINQPad (it is free). That's what I use to test out little ideas in LINQ all the time.

Comment: could you provide a "verbose" version (like in the answer provided by Tim below) of the statement you have above? that would really help out. Or if you know of a place to convert from one to another that would be even better :)

Comment: How can you add another Where clause? for instance Where Customer.Email =='a@a.com' ??

Comment: VERY SLOW: If Blacklists table have 1 million records, it will not work because it will always give error of time out

Comment: Shorter version: `db.Customers.Where(c=>!db.Blacklists.Any(b=>b.CusId==c.CusId))`. However, same SQL expression will be generated by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 6):

How about something like this:

```
var subselect = (from b in BlackList select b.CusId).ToList();

var result = from c in Customer where !subselect.Contains(c.CusId) select c;
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd want to do things this way rather than the way Timothy shared?

Comment: @PeterMajeed well, I'm not sure, but Tim only fetches BlackList once. Timothys BlackList is encased in a `Where` (but it could be that EF optimizes that so that it is only fetched once as well)

Comment: A quick check I did showed that for my code the `BlackList` table was added as a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL AS [Empty] FROM [Blacklist] ...` so it doesn't even retrieve it, SQL does all the work and it is nicely optimized.

Comment: Sorry guys. I just offered the above as something I've used before. When I posted my answer, I hadn't yet seen any other answers.

Comment: @TimRolen All good mate, there are times when your solution is handy, and it definitely works. Just good to be aware that EF will convert it into a `WHERE CusId NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` type of statement. For short lists or where there's extra logic to filter the lists that is the best solution, use it myself often too.

Comment: @TimRolen Also you run two queries instead of one, because `.ToList()` on an `IQueryable` actually enumerates it.

Answer (score 5):

**Any() is the best performance :**

```
db.Customers.Where(c => !db.Blacklists.Any(b => b.CusId == c.Id));
```

If you also need **columns** of Blacklists , use **join** with condition : b.CusId == c.Id

Answer (score 1):

IF in table `BlackList` yo have a List of `Customer` You can perform something like

```
 IEnumerable<Customer> model = (from c in db.Customer
                                from b in c.BlackList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where b.CusID== null
                                  select new Customer
                                   {
                                        CusId= c.OrderID
                                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This query I used and it works perfectly:

```
var query = _context.Customer.Where(x => x.Id == id && !x.BlackList.Any(z => x.Id == x.CustId)).ToList();
```