# Entity Framework query across databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'am struggling to find an efficient way to perform a query across tables using Entity Framework.

I have two tables, one containing objects *Foos*, and the other one containing comparisons between those objects *FooComparisons*. The comparison process between two *Foos* is an heavy calculation.

The request I would like to perform efficiently is : for each Foo into the Database which has no comparison associated, run comparison process against the whole *Foo* datatable except me and store results into *FooComparison* table.

As expected, the *FooComparison* table is getting huge quite fast (for each new *Foo*-n, we add n-1 records to the table) and the way I was performing this operation initially is not sustainable : I store all data into memory to be able to run a LINQ Query against IEnumerable.

What would be the proper way of performing this operation using Entity Framework? I am sure a Join should make the trick but I cannot figure out how.

Thanks for your help.

```
 public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class FooComparison
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Foo1Id { get; set; }
    public int Foo2Id { get; set; }
    public int SimilarityIndex   { get; set; }
}

public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public DbSet<FooComparison> FooComparisons { get; set; }

}

public class ComparisonService
{

    public async Task<int> RunComparisonUpdate(FooContext context)
    {
        var allFoos = context.Foos.ToArray();
        var alreadyRun = context.FooComparisons.Select(x => new {x.Foo1Id, x.Foo2Id}).Distinct().ToArray();
        //we store all data in memory, I cannot perform the LINQ Query below otherwise, I know this is not right way of doing it!

        var toRun = allFoos
            .Where(x => alreadyRun.All(y => y.Foo1Id != x.Id && y.Foo2Id != x.Id)).ToArray(); //complex query that I cannot run directly against the context

        foreach (Foo foo in toRun)
        {
            foreach (Foo other in allFoos)
            {
                if (other.Equals(foo)) continue;
                context.FooComparisons.Add(Compare(foo, other));
            }
        }

        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private FooComparison Compare(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
    {
        //lengthy calculation
        return  new FooComparison()
        {
            Foo1Id = foo1.Id,
            Foo2Id = foo2.Id,
            SimilarityIndex = 42 //result of the calculation

        };
    }
```

**EDIT**

I've found a much better way of doing it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766856/select-records-that-does-not-exist-in-another-table-in-entity-framework/21767082) post. But after implementing it, I get a Request Timeout once every two requests. I could increase the timeout but that doesn't sound a sustainable solution (I guess the timeout will happen again when the DB will get bigger).

Is there any other solution?

```
    public async Task<int> RunComparisonUpdate_MuchBetter(FooContext context)
    {
        var Id1s = context.FooComparisons.Select(x => x.Foo1Id);
        var Id2s = context.FooComparisons.Select(x => x.Foo2Id);
        var toRun = context.Foos.Where(x => !Id1s.Contains(x.Id) && !Id2s.Contains(x.Id)).ToArray();

        foreach (Foo foo in toRun) {
            foreach (Foo other in context.Foos) {
                if (other.Equals(foo)) continue;
                context.FooComparisons.Add(Compare(foo, other));
            }
        }

        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: How much data will return?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: torRun result isbig amount of data?

Comment: @ShervinIvari not necessarily, but FooComparison and Foos Datatables contains millions of rows. I guess that's why the request times out.

Comment: which property you are comparing with? Your foreach is not correct if other is not equal to foo how you can select which foo to add, I think you have two lists, you are comparing them(I need to know how you are comparing) and if object not found you want to add it to another list right? I need to know which property of them is different from the other one. Also, your queries are written in a way that stores data in ram and you have a big amount of data that's why they're not working. Please share more detail about which property you are going to compare

Comment: My queries are definately not stored in RAM, they are running on the server (database) side. I don't undersand the rest of your comment, sorry

Comment: When You call foreach on the result or ToList() You Tell Ef To retrieve data and store it in ram. (until your process done).for example, toRun store result in RAM.they are ways to optimize your query.

Comment: I need to know more detail about your foreachs, the logic is not correct. what makes foo different from other in your foreach.