# Select unique rows from SQL with exclude some rows Mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that I need to select a number of unique rows, but I want to exclude the rows with the same id which are saved in another table.

My first attempt is to select rows which saved before

```
var QuestionsAnswered = await _context.answers
                                  .Where(e => e.Userid == Userid)
                                  .Select(a => new
                                               {
                                                   Qid = a.Questionid
                                               }) .ToListAsync();
```

My return is

```
return View(await _context.questions 
                      .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                      .Take(10)
                      .ToListAsync());
```

what i have done is

```
   var QuestionsAnswered = await _context.answers
                                      .Where(e => e.Userid == Userid)
                                      .Select(a => new
                                                   {
                                                       Qid = a.Questionid
                                                   }) .ToListAsync();

 var AllQuestions =   await _context.questions.ToListAsync();


                foreach (var qid in AllQuestions)
                {
                    int QuestionValueId = qid.QuestionId;

                    foreach (var item in QuestionsAnswered)
                    {
                        if (item.Qid == QuestionValueId)
                        {
                            AllQuestions.RemoveAll(a => a.QuestionId == QuestionValueId);

                        }
                    }
```

but no sense

Comment: Could you not do something like. select from table a where a.id not in (select id from table b). Is this not like something you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766856/select-records-that-does-not-exist-in-another-table-in-entity-framework

Comment: I'm not seeing any SQL here... It should be simple enough to do though, something like this ought to do it: select * from tbl1 a where a.id not in (select distinct(b.id) from tbl2 b)

Comment: yes i try something like this var subselect = (from b in BlackList select b.CusId).ToList();

var result = from c in Customer where !subselect.Contains(c.CusId) select c; but not working will it loop in list of items